# Not able to assign custom home page layout for partner portal users

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I have created a custom home page layout and assign it to partner portal profile and community site profile also. But whenever i logged into portal it was showing me the default home page layout. 
Can anyone help me out. Thanks!!